# No component factory found for ContactUsComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents? in angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7, ng-modules

Getting this error when trying to render a modalcomponent from my component.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [...],
  exports: [...],
  entryComponents: [ContactUsComponent,..],
  declarations: [ContactUsComponent,...],
  providers: [...]
})
```

Have included both in entrycomponents and declarations
but still the error.

Comment: are you using angular material, for modal component ?

Comment: provide more details, which line throws this?